# Python: Calculating the centroid of points in polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, centroid

I am using data on globular clusters to estimate the location of the center of the galaxy. With my data I have plotted a polar graph using matplotlib with the distance to each point as the distance and the right ascension as the angle. My code:

```
points = {'angle': [], 'pos': [], 'dec': [], 'label': []}

for key in RAs.keys():

    points['angle'].append(RAs[key])
    points['pos'].append(d_nominal[key])
    points['label'].append(key)
    points['dec'].append(Decs[key])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_ylim(0,30000)

for x, y in zip( points['angle'], points['pos']):

    ax.scatter(x, y )
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

My question is, how would I calculate the center of this distribution so that i can estimate the galactic center's right ascension and distance?

Comment: Convert to cartesian coordinates, calculate the mean, tranform the mean back to polar coordinates. Note however, that this is only valid in true 2D space, which our universe is not.

Comment: Didn't think of that for some reason. Just did it and it seems reasonable, Thanks!!